# Efficiency of water distillation vs active Condensation Trap

Tags: water-resources, refrigeration

I was wondering what would be more efficient means of producing clean water. The first method could be though a distillation process where by you boil contaminated water and collect the water vapor (similar to "sling shot" water purifier), the next method would be to cool plates and collect the condensation.

The first method would require you to head up a lot of water just to cool it back down again, but the second method is possible highly inefficient as you are cooling a lot of air just o get a small amount of water vapour to condensate. Any one know of any calculations or studies that have addressed this question?

Comment: What "efficiency" are you considering? Both of the methods that you listed can be done completely passively so they would have infinite efficiency. Please add more information and requirements.